# How do I control the LED on an external disk?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, storage

I have seven 4TB Sabrent Thunderbolt 3 external NVMe SSDs. Unfortunately, they appear identical, and targeted disk activity (including unmounting / mounting) is surprisingly not a reliable way of differentiating between the disks.

I understand that I could label them, but they do have LEDs, and if I could toggle a specific drive's LED I could easily identify that drive.

How, if at all, do I control a particular drive's LED?

~~

Big Sur 11.5.1, M1 MacBook Pro + two OWC TB4 docks.

Comment: If the driver for the enclosure supports controlling the LEDs, then yes. If not, then no.

Comment: That makes sense. Is there a way to retrieve the commands supported by the enclosure, or is that "ask the manufacturer" territory?

Comment: Either the manufacturer publishes this information it is available online to be found by you. If they don't, then we won't know it here either.

Answer (score 0):

Control of aspects of a drive enclosure by the computer are governed by the drivers available for that enclosure.

The details or specifications of a specific driver for specific hardware may be published by the manufacturer, in which case you can look for the product data sheets from them. If the manufacturer has not provided this information, we won't know it here either.